# In Cysharp ConsoleAppFramework how can I create a sub sub command?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I'm trying to create a command under a command under a command in the ConsoleAppFramework.

Something where you can get:

```
./mycli topTool subcategory action1 -u somearg

./mycli topTool subcategory action2
```

I've tried adding

```
[Command("subcategory action1")]
public void Action1([Option("u", "arg")] string arg) {}

[Command("subcategory action2")]
public void Action2() {}
```

But that just results in `Command not found. args: topTool subcategory action2`

I've also tried

```
[Command(new [] { "subcategory", "action1" }]
public void Action1(...) {}

[Command(new [] { "subcategory", "action2" }]
public void Action2() {}
```

But that throws an exception of duplicate command names.

I've also added a sub class inside the top level class and the framework doesn't pick it up. Is this even possible or do I have to rethink my whole structure?

Comment: What is subcategory actually doing; why is it needed?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - If you think about the Azure CLI tool to manage resources you can dig into another application. So if I wanted to manage a postgresql database I can do `az postgres db create` or `az postgres db drop` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest